# How to change variable from one TPU device for all TPU devices?

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory, tpu

Can I change variable within one TPU device so that it could be changed for other TPU devices ?

I tried the following approach:

```
!pip install cloud-tpu-client==0.10 https://storage.googleapis.com/tpu-pytorch/wheels/torch_xla-1.6-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
import torch
import torch_xla.core.xla_model as xm
a=torch.tensor([2], device=torch.device("cpu"))
def tr(rank, flags):
  device = xm.xla_device()  
  global a
  if xm.is_master_ordinal():
    a=torch.tensor([3], device=torch.device("cpu"))
  xm.rendezvous('download_only_once')
  b = a.to(device)
  print(b)

import torch_xla.distributed.xla_multiprocessing as xmp
flags={}
xmp.spawn(tr, args=(flags,), nprocs=8, start_method='fork')
```

It doesn't work: the variable is not changing for other devices.